# Unable to save file: Permission denied 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\

Tags: python, odoo

I create new module in `odoo 11` in windows 10. If I create a new models but it can not be save the changes. It provides an error is:

```
Unable to save file: Permission denied 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\new_module\models\models.py'
```

Comment: Is this file open somewhere? That's the reason you are getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Windows requires administrator privileges to write/modify files in `C:\Program Files`.
Try running your script as an administrator.